# Color states with Python's matplotlib/basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis

I want to generate a map of the United States and color each state in using a different shade. Is there a way to do this using Python's basemap?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a nicely formated example in the Basemap repo on GitHub: [fillstates.py](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/blob/master/examples/fillstates.py). The shapefile ([dbf](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/raw/master/examples/st99_d00.dbf) | [shp](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/raw/master/examples/st99_d00.shp) | [shx](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/raw/master/examples/st99_d00.shx)) is also included in the [examples folder](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/blob/master/examples/).

Here is an abbreviated version of the example:

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

# create the map
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-119,llcrnrlat=22,urcrnrlon=-64,urcrnrlat=49,
        projection='lcc',lat_1=33,lat_2=45,lon_0=-95)

# load the shapefile, use the name 'states'
map.readshapefile('st99_d00', name='states', drawbounds=True)

# collect the state names from the shapefile attributes so we can
# look up the shape obect for a state by it's name
state_names = []
for shape_dict in map.states_info:
    state_names.append(shape_dict['NAME'])

ax = plt.gca() # get current axes instance

# get Texas and draw the filled polygon
seg = map.states[state_names.index('Texas')]
poly = Polygon(seg, facecolor='red',edgecolor='red')
ax.add_patch(poly)

plt.show()
```

Resulting plot with Texas filled red:

[image: Resulting plot with Texas filled red]

Note that when we load a shapefile the shapes and attributes are stored in `map.states` and `map.states_info` respectively as lists based on the `name` parameter used in the `readshapefile` call. So to look up the shape for a specific state we had to build a corresponding list of the state names from the attributes.

Comment: That's really great. If I want to put a star on a particular lat/lon, how would I add that?

Comment: @vy32 here is a good [example of plotting point data on a map](https://www.getdatajoy.com/examples/python-plots/plot-data-points-on-a-map), all of the marker styles can be found in the [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html), specifically `*` is the start marker.

Comment: @GonzaloGarcia absolutely, it just depends on the shapefile having a "NAME" field for each polygon.

Comment: How to add the state name or abbreviation, or plot data at a state?